# Concurrent processing of user Messages in SQS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

We have several consumer processes which poll from a standard SQS and process the message. Each message is associated with a user. For each user, we can process 100 messages per minute. Beyond that, the API which we are using for processing would start giving 500 errors.

Now since the Queue contains messages for other users, we can't cherry-pick those users since they have their quota under the limit.

One solution to this is using FIFO and implementing message groups. But FIFO has a peculiar limitation.

> You can have a maximum of 20,000 in-flight messages

This would have been completely fine, but the issue is that when a message is in flight from a message group, SQS adds the count of all the messages in that group to the in-flight count.

This article explains more in detail:

[https://tomgregory.com/3-surprising-facts-about-aws-sqs-fifo-queues/#:~:text=A%20FIFO%20queue%20has%20a%20maximum%20inflight%20message%20limit%20of%2020%2C000](https://tomgregory.com/3-surprising-facts-about-aws-sqs-fifo-queues/#:%7E:text=A%20FIFO%20queue%20has%20a%20maximum%20inflight%20message%20limit%20of%2020%2C000).

In this article read "**20,000 message buffer**" header. That might explain what's happening.

https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/sqs-message-backlog/

The second solution which I could think of is to make the producer of the microservice smart. But in our case, the producer is a completely different microservice. And the owners of that microservice hardly listen.

We definitely want our consumers to scale to provide minimum wait time to each user but can't because of the above reasons.

I genuinely feel SQS was not the correct choice for this design, but can't convince my superiors of the same.

Is there a way we can overcome this situation or did we hit a dead end?

Comment: In theory you can just raise an exception for the 101st message for a user and continue with the next message, hoping that eventually you receive messages by other users and process all these messages and the 100+ messages of a single user do not clog up the system.

Comment: And I am really not sure about the in-flight message limit mentioned in the article. I would ask for specific clarification by AWS support in that situation before discarding FIFO. But regardless of that issue FIFO does not fix the issue of too many user messages processed per minute (or does the processing of the message always take longer than 1/100 of a minute?)

Comment: Agreed but there are scenarios when there are two users in the queue, where user1 has 100k messages while user2 has 10k. The ratio is not something we can calculate. Also, the no of users is unpredictable.
In the case where individual users have a high count, we might end up hitting the 120k in-flight limit. The range would be between 80-120. But we are ready for exponential backoff in that cases.

Comment: Is it desired that your system takes 17 hours to process 100k messages by a single user?

Comment: Yea. It's like a request that our customer has generated and we would like to serve him as soon as possible. We can add 1-2 hours. But that's the ceiling,

Comment: Just extra info: We have created a separate priority queue for requests which have less than 1000 messages. Consumers tend to finish the priority queue first and then they move on to the normal queue.

Answer (score 1):

> This would have been completely fine, but the issue is that when a
> message is in flight from a message group, SQS adds the count of all
> the messages in that group to the in-flight count

I do not think this is the case for a FIFO. I am using a FIFO where I process one message at a time per consumer(There are 3 of them). There are SQS messages from the same message group, but the inflight message count for me is always 3, i.e each of the 3 consumers processing one of them. When either of them processes the message, and the processing time for each SQS message is variable here, it picks up the next one in the queue. The inflight messages count remains 3 all the time.

Comment: Can you once try the experiment mentioned in the article and confirm back.? @BackEndMacavity

Comment: I think the experiment in the article mentioned is a little skewed. There is one consumer and messages are being batched in lots of 10 and being sent across 100 times over. SQS supports a MaxNumberOfMessages attribute where you can control the number of incoming messages one can process. If not mentioned, it will try and process everything and would almost be as good/bad as a standard queue. I also found another article [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55156344/aws-sqs-relationship-between-number-of-queue-consumers-and-the-number-of-in-fl) which might help clear some air.

Comment: Also setting up a dead letter queue would go a long way in helping unblock the queue. Also following the scenarios mentioned [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/using-messagegroupid-property.html) could help avoid the problems author is alluding to.

Comment: Also there are visibility, wait time and delivery delay settings involved which also impact the behavior, so these also need to be factored in

Comment: Try this experiment once:
https://pastebin.com/DD61bFfK

I've tried it myself and got the same results. Please let me know if you get any different. @BackEndMacavity

Comment: In this article read "20,000 message buffer" header. That might explain what's happening.
https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/sqs-message-backlog/

Comment: Before I give this a try, could you clarify, that when you say "receive a single message from the queue, Message1", you are actually deleting it as well? If you don't it is going to inflight message and none of the messages in the same message group would get processed.